# iOS - Import Objective-C static library into Swift Dynamic Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I need to import more than one Objective-C static librarys into my current Swift Dynamic framework. I don't know how to do that. Is there any idea about to add at least one static library to Swift Dynamic framework or any sample project like that?

Comment: Why do you think importing the second one would work any different from importing the first one?

Comment: First I don't know how to import that first one here.